# Map syntax in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I stumbled across this syntax in a groovy script :

```
a[x,y]
```

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a way of [slicing](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Slicingwiththesubscriptoperator) with the *[subscript operator](http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#subscript-operator)*:

> The subscript operator is a short hand notation for `getAt` or `putAt`,
>   depending on whether you find it on the left hand side or the right
>   hand side of an assignment

You can use it on lists, arrays, maps and also strings:

```
def a = 'hello'
assert a[0,1] == 'he'
assert a[0..1] == 'he'
assert a[0..2] == 'hel'
assert a[0,2] == 'hl'
assert a[0,2,4] == 'hlo'
assert a[0..-1] == 'hello'
assert a[0..-2] == 'hell'
```

An example with `getAt` and `putAt`:

```
def list = [1, 0, 3, 0, 5]
list[1,3] = [2,4]
assert list == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```